# Angular HttpRequest doesn't send Params

Tags: angular, httprequest

I'm trying to send parameters to a simple GET request using HttpRequest. But it seems that it does not send the parameters.

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params.set("page", "4");

let req = new HttpRequest<any>(
  "GET",
  "https://reqres.in/api/users",
  null,
  { params }
);

this.http
  .request<any>(req)
  .pipe(
    map(_r => {
      let _resp = _r as HttpResponse<any>;
      return _resp.body;
    })
  )
  .subscribe(s => console.log(s));
```

The above code should return the result for page 4. But it only works if I insert **"?page=4"** in the
URL.

**Running Code:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-request-dont-send-params?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HttpParams() object is immutable. It returns a new copy of params every time you call it.

```
  // Change to this

let params = new HttpParams().set("page", "4");

// Or you could do this

let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.set("page", "4");
```

That should get it working for you. Works in the running code you shared. https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-request-dont-send-params-nku9kc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

try using:

**new HttpParams().append()** for sending query parameters

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params.append("page", "4");
```

try check on this
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/http-request-dont-send-params-j4bvqa?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

I think this will help you

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use following code

```
const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: { page: 4, size: 10, order: 'desc'}});
```

This way you can add as many parameters as you want